# Can we use multiple tables(created on fly) for a single model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `TempUser` that is used for data crunching using lots of queries to narrow down the result.  Its a replica of User Model. For narrowing down the result it copies the all the records from users_table into `temp_users_table` and keeps deleting record according to filters applied on it so that in the end I only have filtered users in TempUser model where I can perform more active record operations on the residual data.

I am trying to make dynamic tables for TempUser Model so that If more than one user request for TempUser Model then he should have different temp_user_dynamic_table to perform operations on it. Is it possible?

something like:-

```
class TempUser < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

which has multiple dynamic tables created on fly when new request comes in like:- `temp_users_table1`,`temp_users_table2`

Comment: This sounds like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Comment: thanks for response @spickermann but my question is a straight shoot that Can we use multiple tables(created on fly) for a single model in rails? I gave a little bit of history of my question just because if it can help stackoverflowers to get the more clear context of my problem.

Comment: Why don't you just add a column like `current_user_id` to the table to identify which user the subset belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem in doing something like

```
temp_model = Class.new(TempUser) do
  set_table_name your_dynamically_created_table_name
end

temp_model.find(...blah...)
```

But I agree with @spickermann, this definitely looks like XY problem.